# Converting Hex String To Float

Tags: php, hex

Hi I need to convert this HEX String `6BE15C3E` into a float. I have been using an Arduino to do this in the past and below is the code I would use to convert the HEX into a float on an Arduino.

```
uint8_t l[] = {0x6b, 0xe1, 0x5c, 0x3e};
float var1;
memcpy(&var1, l, 4);
Serial.println(var1);
```

The result of the above code is 0.22 which is correct. I've tried using the following code in PHP but I don't get the correct answer:

```
print_r(hex2float("6BE15C3E"));
function hex2float($strHex) {
    $hex = sscanf($strHex, "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x");
    $hex = array_reverse($hex);
    $bin = implode('', array_map('chr', $hex));
    $array = unpack("dnum", $bin);
    return $array['num'];
}
```

This code is returning `4.56588239954E+211` which seems way off and I'm not sure why. I know the Arduino example has been converted into bytes before hand but I don't know if this needs to be done in PHP.

Comment: I just updated my question I made a mistake of using the wrong value in my example.

Comment: There are a couple of issues with this - the `d` in your unpack is expecting a 64bit double and your trying to use a 32bit number.  32bit is probably right for an Arduino, but any laptop etc this will be more like a float (`f`), so trying a few things I changed that to `G` and updated the original value to `ae47613e` and I get (close to) 0.22 (To change the unpack to `f` you need to remove the `array_reverse`)

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you I just tried that and got close to 0.22 as well. This might be a stupid question but how did you convert `6BE15C3E` into `ae47613e` is that just the 64bit version?

Comment: Can't explain how I converted it - that would be telling trade secrets :) OK I cheated and reversed the process - I ran `pack("f", 0.22)` and printed the result out in hex.

Comment: Thank you for letting me in on that little secret ;) ahah

Comment: I can't up vote the comment because I'm not high enough rank. But that did fix my issue! Thank you

Comment: You can post it as an answer yourself (AFAIK) just to resolve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Nigel Ren for fixing this issue. Here is the code used to fix the issue:

```
function hex2float($strHex) {
    $hex = sscanf($strHex, "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x");
    $bin = implode('', array_map('chr', $hex));
    $array = unpack("f", $bin);
    return $array[1];
}
```

When inputting `6BE15C3E` it returns `0.215...` which is the correct answer when rounded up.

Comment: I suggest there are 2 problems with this answer:  (1) FLOAT is 32 bits, yet the sscanf specifies 64.  (2) The 'normal' representation for IEEE-754 single precision is in the reverse order, so that 1.0 --> 3F800000.  What you have is expecting the hex to be 0000803F.  Because of (1), a simple `array_reverse()` will not fix (2).

Answer (score 1):

These are probably not optimal, but I think they work:

```
function hex2float($strHex) {
    $hex = sscanf($strHex, "%02x%02x%02x%02x");
    $hex = array_reverse($hex);
    $bin = implode('', array_map('chr', $hex));
    $array = unpack("f", $bin);
    return $array[1];
}

function float2hex($f)
{
    $a = unpack("I", pack( "f", $f ));
    $w = pack("N", $a[1] );
    return bin2hex($w);
}
```

Tests:

```
function Test($hex)
{
    $f = hex2float($hex);
    $hex2 = float2hex($f);
    echo "$hex --> $f --> $hex2<br>\n";
}


3f800000 --> 1 --> 3f800000
40000000 --> 2 --> 40000000
bf800000 --> -1 --> bf800000
c0000000 --> -2 --> c0000000
6BE15C3E --> 5.448878216557E+26 --> 6be15c3e
3E5CE16B --> 0.21570365130901 --> 3e5ce16b
```

Assuming your Arduino and your PHP script are running on different "endian" machines, then the `array_reverse()` should be removed from `hex2float` to 'fix' that function.  (And `float2hex` will need some kind of reverse to make it match.)

I have not thought through what it would take to implement conversion between `DOUBLE` and hex.